# Entity Framework: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime, localdb

I have a class Announcment:

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models {

    public partial class Announcment {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Subject")]
        public String Subject { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [DisplayName("Content")]
        public String Text { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Published")]
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Author")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and I create it like this. The date `TimeStamp` is set automatically to `DateTime.Now`:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Subject,Text")] Announcment announcment) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                //MINE 
                var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                Debug.WriteLine("USER" + user.Id);
                announcment.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
                announcment.Author = user;
                //
                db.Announcments.Add(announcment);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(announcment);
        }
```

and it works without any trouble. No errors.

But then I want to edit it. The view for editing looks like this. It is standard `Edit` action generated by Visual Studio 2013. I just removed editor for `@model.TimeStamp`.

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Announcment

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Announcment</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subject, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", rows =  8} })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

and then POST `Edit` method runs. Only thing I did here is deleting binding to `,TimeStamp` because I do not edit it. I got same results with or without it.

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Subject,Text")] Announcment announcment) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                db.Entry(announcment).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(announcment);
        }
```

and I get this evil error:

```
Błąd serwera w aplikacji '/'.

The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated. 
  Opis: Podczas wykonywania bieżącego żądania sieci Web wystąpił nieobsługiwany wyjątek. Aby uzyskać dodatkowe informacje o błędzie i miejscu jego występowania w kodzie, przejrzyj ślad stosu. 

 Szczegóły wyjątku: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Błąd źródła: 



Wiersz 86:                 Debug.WriteLine(announcment.TimeStamp);
Wiersz 87:                 db.Entry(announcment).State = EntityState.Modified;
Wiersz 88:                 db.SaveChanges();
Wiersz 89:                 return RedirectToAction("Index");
Wiersz 90:             }


 Plik źródłowy:  c:\Users\R\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Controllers\AnnouncmentsController.cs    Wiersz:  88 

Ślad stosu: 



[SqlException (0x80131904): The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1789294
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5340642
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1421
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +208
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +163
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +36
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +138
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +476
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +177
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) +1382
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +236

[UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +488
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut) +32
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction) +272
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update() +143
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35() +34
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +448
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction) +219
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27() +71
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +211
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction) +408
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) +39
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +320

[DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +366
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +56
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +52
   WebApplication2.Controllers.AnnouncmentsController.Edit(Announcment announcment) in c:\Users\R\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Controllers\AnnouncmentsController.cs:88
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +181
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +434
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9690172
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155




Informacje o wersji: Wersja Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319; Wersja ASP.NET:4.0.30319.34009
```

**Question:** Why do I get this exception when I don't even try to edit property `TimeStamp` for the `Announcment`? How to fix this?

EDIT: I found that even when I do not try to edit original date it is mysteriously set to:
 `0001-01-01 00:00:00`

Comment: What is the type of `TimeStamp` column in database? I assume it is `datetime` ? There is a difference between date ranges for [datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) and [datetime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb677335.aspx) types in sql. If you're not changing `TimeStamp` on your model, I would suggest to check what's the value of `TimeStamp`, and if it is less than `January 1, 1753`, set it to `January 1, 1753` since this is the min date, that `datetime` type accepts in sql.

Comment: @michaelmoore I checked it in Server Explorer. It is `datetime`. I do not understand second part of your comment. Why do I have to change the `TimeStamp` while I want to keep `TimeStamp` created during `POST Create` action?

Comment: @michaelmoore EDIT tries to change date to ` 0001-01-01 00:00:00` but why when I don't even try to edit it in view?

Comment: When you're debugging Edit action, do you see what's the value of `TimeStamp` ? Is it bigger than `January 1, 1753` ? Also, might be a good idea to run sql profiler, and see t-sql that is running against sql server when you are saving edited announcement.

Comment: good, so now we know why you have this exception (if it is not clear, let me know I'll try to explain it again). Now let's think why it is actually changing TimeStamp date. One workaround that comes to mind is, try to bind it to some hidden field on edit view, and see if that helps.

Comment: @michaelmoore I added  ` @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TimeStamp)` to `Edit` view and it displays: `2014-09-04 18:33:37 `

Comment: Add this `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TimeStamp)` somewhere in your view.

Comment: just out of curiosity, is this Polish? `Błąd serwera w aplikacji`

Comment: @michaelmoore Yes, it is, I had problems with changing it to English. You probably know it from context but it means: "Server application error". If you want to ask sth more, go ahead.

Comment: No I'm fine, I see, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In edit of post you have to bind `TimeStamp` property as well, in null case it take the value that is shown in the post, so put it in hidden field if you don't want the user to change it:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.TimeStamp)
```

Otherwise, it will be posted null and in that case it will be changed to `0001-01-01 00:00:00` in database side which is not valid `DateTime` and you will get the exception

Comment: But why only `TimeStamp` is forgotten. I don not edit: `public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }` and it does not forget the author after edit. I also don't edit id.

Comment: that is your relationship table so that is not effected

Comment: Thanks.Ok, but also I do not edit `Id` and it is in the same table.

Comment: Edit has `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)` in your view.

Comment: @michaelmoore I did not notice. Thank you.